# Problem in creating dynamic table layout

Tags: android, dynamic, tablelayout

I have created a dynamic TableLayout and I have given an image to TableRow's Background.But my problem is the image is taking its actual size not what I am setting.I want that image should take the height and width defined by me.
Please Help Me.

My Code is...

```
void createRows()
{
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        String name = "Hareesh Kumar Gangadhara";
        String time = "2:53 PM";
        String date = "06/05/11";
        String time_date =time+" "+date;
        String message = "Hello Prashant";
        TableRow row_message = new TableRow(this);
        ImageView friend_img = new ImageView(this);
        LinearLayout layout_msg_info = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout layout_name_date = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout layout_message = new LinearLayout(this);

        friend_img.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(35,35));

        friend_img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.archit);

        TextView tv_name = new TextView(this);
        TextView tv_time_date = new TextView(this);
        TextView tv_message = new TextView(this);

        tv_name.setText(name);
        tv_time_date.setText(time_date);
        tv_message.setText(message);

        tv_name.setTextColor(color_black);
        tv_time_date.setTextColor(color_black);
        tv_message.setTextColor(color_black);


        tv_name.setTextSize(14);
        tv_time_date.setTextSize(10);
        tv_message.setTextSize(12);


        layout_name_date.addView(tv_name);
        layout_name_date.addView(tv_time_date);
        layout_message.addView(tv_message);

        layout_msg_info.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        layout_msg_info.setPadding(30, 10, 0, 0);
        layout_msg_info.addView(layout_name_date);
        layout_msg_info.addView(layout_message);

        row_message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img_message_back);
        row_message.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,40));
        row_message.setPadding(0, 0, 10, 5);
        row_message.addView(friend_img);
        row_message.addView(layout_msg_info);

        table_message.addView(row_message);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TableRow.LayoutParams` instead of `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`.

Hope it Helps

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set the ScaleType value on your ImageView.

Here's the ScaleType reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

You're probably looking to set it to FIT_XY or CENTER_INSIDE.